# PHP:problems in getting values from a associative array using foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get values from  a complex associative array it is obtained from an xml file.Here is the actual output of array (https://www.dropbox.com/s/k6lxrx6h9x3x83u/xml-first.txt?dl=0).

Here is a sample

```
Array
(
    [drawserialnumber] => 48285
    [lotteryname] => Akshaya
    [shortname] => AK
    [drawdate] => 2015-06-17
    [drawheld] => Array
        (
        )

    [drawnumber] => 194
    [drawvenew] => SREE CHITHRA HOME AUDITORIUM, PAZHAVANGADI, EAST FORT, THIRUVANANTHAPURAM
    [approvedby] => A.Jayakumar
    [approverdesig] => Deputy Director
    [approveroffice] => Directorate Of State Lotteries , Vikas Bhavan,tvm
    [prizes] => Array
        (
            [prizedetails] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [prizeno] => 1
                            [prizedesc] => Rs :6,500,000/-
                            [totalamt] => 6500000
                            [conslation] => f
                            [prizeticket] => Array
                                (
                                    [seriesname] => AK
                                    [digit] => 279045
                                    [district] => THRISSUR
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [prizeno] => 1
                            [prizedesc] => Rs :10,000/-
                            [totalamt] => 10000
                            [conslation] => t
                            [prizeticket] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [seriesname] => AJ
                                            [digit] => 279045
                                            [district] => NIL
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [seriesname] => AR
                                            [digit] => 279045
                                            [district] => NIL
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [seriesname] => AM
                                            [digit] => 279045
                                            [district] => NIL
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [seriesname] => AO
                                            [digit] => 279045
                                            [district] => NIL
                                        )

                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [seriesname] => AP
                                            [digit] => 279045
                                            [district] => NIL
                                        )

                                    [5] => Array
                                        (
                                            [seriesname] => AL
                                            [digit] => 279045
                                            [district] => NIL
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [prizeno] => 2
                            [prizedesc] => Rs :200,000/-
                            [totalamt] => 200000
                            [conslation] => f
                            [prizeticket] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [seriesname] => AR
                                            [digit] => 420734
                                            [district] => KANNUR
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [seriesname] => AJ
                                            [digit] => 221136
                                            [district] => ALAPPUZHA
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [seriesname] => AK
                                            [digit] => 825429
                                            [district] => WAYANAD
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [seriesname] => AL
                                            [digit] => 171621
                                            [district] => THIRUVANANTHAPURAM
                                        )

                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [seriesname] => AM
                                            [digit] => 786170
                                            [district] => ERNAKULAM
                                        )

                                    [5] => Array
                                        (
                                            [seriesname] => AO
                                            [digit] => 668158
                                            [district] => PALAKKAD
                                        )

                                    [6] => Array
                                        (
                                            [seriesname] => AP
                                            [digit] => 244326
                                            [district] => KANNUR
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [prizeno] => 3
                            [prizedesc] => Rs :10,000/-
                            [totalamt] => 10000
                            [conslation] => f
                            [prizeticket] => Array
                                (
                                    [seriesname] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [digit] => 25426
                                    [district] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [prizeno] => 4
                            [prizedesc] => Rs :5,000/-
                            [totalamt] => 5000
                            [conslation] => f
                            [prizeticket] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [seriesname] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [digit] => 6989
                                            [district] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [seriesname] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [digit] => 3242
                                            [district] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )
```

and so on for may occurances

Now i want to get the details to an html table ,its almost done but the problem is 
`pricedetails` array.

Here is the code for getting `pricedetails`

```
foreach ($data['prizes'] as $prizes) {

    foreach($prizes as $prize){ 

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($prize);
        echo '</pre>';
        $temp=$prize['prizeticket'];

            foreach($temp as $ticket){ 
            print_r($ticket);

    }
  }
}
```

Here is the two iterations of `Print_r($prize)`

```
Array
(
    [prizeno] => 1
    [prizedesc] => Rs :6,500,000/-
    [totalamt] => 6500000
    [conslation] => f
    [prizeticket] => Array
        (
            [seriesname] => AK
            [digit] => 279045
            [district] => THRISSUR
        )

)
Array
(
    [prizeno] => 1
    [prizedesc] => Rs :10,000/-
    [totalamt] => 10000
    [conslation] => t
    [prizeticket] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [seriesname] => AJ
                    [digit] => 279045
                    [district] => NIL
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [seriesname] => AR
                    [digit] => 279045
                    [district] => NIL
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [seriesname] => AM
                    [digit] => 279045
                    [district] => NIL
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [seriesname] => AO
                    [digit] => 279045
                    [district] => NIL
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [seriesname] => AP
                    [digit] => 279045
                    [district] => NIL
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [seriesname] => AL
                    [digit] => 279045
                    [district] => NIL
                )

        )

)
```

As you see the first iteration contains only one sub array under `prizedetails` and the second iterations contains more than one sub arrays under `prizedetails`.
The problem i can't get the values with both key-value pairs.

`print_r($ticket)` output

```
AK
279045
THRISSUR
Array
(
    [seriesname] => AJ
    [digit] => 279045
    [district] => NIL
)
Array
(
    [seriesname] => AR
    [digit] => 279045
    [district] => NIL
)
```

Notice that first output `AK
    279045
    THRISSUR`
printed without any key and its like a text and the rest is outputted correctly,but i need to print all of with the array keys.I know this is because the `print_r($prize)` first iteration contains only one sub array under `prizedetails`.How can i solve it?

**UPDATE**
Code for parsing xml

```
$data=json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($lottery)),1);
```

Comment: Try to generate xml properly so that every `prizeticket` will have the same structure

Comment: What code are you using to parse the XML into an array?

Comment: You're using a very hacky method of getting that XML into your array, and it's hard to know if the original source was correctly formatted, or an array level was discarded by the many layers of casting you used between `simplexml_load_string()` and the JSON enc/dec. SimpleXML should probably be used directly to retrieve the values you need rather than first trying to cast an array. Post a sample of the source XML that includes both the single and multiple examples of `prizeticket`.

Comment: Can you show the **original data source**, as it might be the `encode(decode())` you are using to convert an object into an array via a JSON onject and array, that is causing some kind of curruption to the original data. By the way what wrong with using the OBJECT.

Comment: @riggs original xml (https://www.dropbox.com/s/imu7nnvqakwqxuu/AK-194.xml?dl=0)

Comment: Ok that XML validates, so its probably the JSON fiddling that is causing some kind of corruption.

Comment: Use the object thats why `simplexml_load_string($lottery)` returns an object. You could try removing the cast to array `(array)simplexml_load_string($lottery)` to `simplexml_load_string($lottery)` as casting to an array will likely loose info

Answer (score 0):

Your code is behaving correctly. You need to alter the code such that "IF" prizeticket has one item, it does one thing, "ELSE" it does something else.

```
if(!isset($prize['prizeticket'][0])) // It has one item
    print_r($prize['prizeticket']);
else foreach($prize['prizeticket'] as $ticket)
    print_r($ticket);
```

This is a good place to use a function. Suppose it was named `handle_a_ticket($ticket)', you would replace print_r with handle_a_ticket.

Comment: No, they need to generate the correct **Valid** XML and then there will be no difference in the structure.

Comment: It is very misguided to assume that everyone in the world received perfect data. It is normal for data to be malformed. In this case, the XML is actually just fine. It is NORMAL for a field of XML to be a single entity in one place and a collection in another.

Comment: Yes but look at the full data things get very odd in and after after occurance[3]

Comment: I agree. The source - which appears to be coming from someone else - appears to have missing data. From my point of view, having spent over 30 years moving data around, you have to take what you get and make it work as best you can. It is rarely an option to say, "I'm not doing this until you fix your data." In this case, his code fix was trivial.

Comment: See his conversion mecanism to get an array from an object. I bet thats the source of these corruptions.

Comment: That wasn't there before. He is apparently taking an XML string, converting it to XML, casting it to an array (which is lossy), converting it to JSON, and converting it back to an array. Looks like copy-and-paste programming, which is not uncommon in questions around here.

Comment: No he just added it after a request for more info. It rather explains the reason for his problems.

Answer (score 0):

My first reaction is that the XML has a typo.

```
[prizeticket] => Array
    (
        [seriesname] => AK
        [digit] => 279045
        [district] => THRISSUR
    )
```

Should instead look like:

```
[prizeticket] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [seriesname] => AK
                [digit] => 279045
                [district] => THRISSUR
            )
```

If you have some requirement that you absolutely must leave the XML the way it is, I'd suggest checking for the existence of index 0 like this:

```
foreach($temp as $tickets) { 
    if(!isset($tickets[0]) {
        //do something with $ticket
    }
    else {
        foreach($tickets as $ticket) {
            //do something with $ticket
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution based on @RiggsFolly's comments.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file('AK-194.xml');

foreach($xml->prizes as $prize){

 foreach($prize->prizedetails as $details){

   foreach($details->prizeticket as $tickets){
        print_r($tickets);
      }
    }
}
```